# SQLException in java: No value specified for parameter 2

Tags: java, mysql

I'm having trouble with solving this problem :/. When I run my project I encounter the error code: no value specified for parameter 2, even though all parameters should be filled in.

```
public Field geefVeld(int x, int y, String spelname, int spelbordnr) {
    Field field = null;
    //connection.close();
    try (Connection connectie = DriverManager.getConnection(Connectie.JDBC_URL)) {
        PreparedStatement query = connectie.prepareStatement("SELECT symbool FROM field WHERE XCoord = ? and YCoord = ? and Spelbord_spel_Spelname = ? and Spelbord_VolgordeID = ?");
        query.setInt(1, x);
        query.setInt(2, y); 
        query.setString(3, spelname); 
        query.setInt(4, spelbordnr);

        try (ResultSet rs = query.executeQuery()) {
            field = new Field(rs.getString(3).charAt(0));
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        throw new RuntimeException(ex);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

    return field;
}
```

When debugging i can see that x = 0, y = 0, spelname = "Soraka", spelbordnr = 1 (Wich is all totally fine, because these values excist in my database)

The project stops at "query.setInt(2, y);" when debugging.

I apoligize if I'm overlooking something silly, but I've been searching for hours and I can't seem to find it :(

Any response is welcome :p

Comment: No problem, I have not worked with these technologies for a while, however, I believe your problem lies here: new Field(rs.getString(3).charAt(0)); You are selecting a single column, yet, you try to reach the third. The numbering, if I recall correctly, starts from 1 at rs getters, so, the error message might tell you the second parameter is missing if the error reporter starts the numbering from 0. It's a wild guess only.

Comment: What exception is thrown?

Comment: Please add the full exception stack trace to your question.

Comment: Are you sure YCoord has complitable type in SQL table?

Answer (score 1):

You are not retrieving your resultset correctly in several respects.  First, you need to use the `next()` method to fetch the row or rows in the result. Second, you are calling `getString(3)` where you only have one column (`symbol`) in your resultset. Third, don't forget to close your resultset. Finally, there's something strange about the way you wrote your `try`.

```
try {
    ResultSet rs = query.executeQuery();
    while(rs.next()) {
         field = new Field(rs.getString(1).charAt(0));
    }
    rs.close();
}
```

I don't know if that will fix the parameter-setting issue but it is worth a try.

Comment: Are you aware of "try with resources"? The way he wrote his `try` is the correct way in modern Java to make sure the resource (result set) is closed.

Comment: Thx for the response, apperantly there was nothing wrong wit the code ( or maybe there still is and I'm not aware of it :/), but there was a problem with NetBeans. The "clean build" function doesn't really work for some reason, so I needed to manually delete the build ( I hope I'm making sense :p )

Answer (score 0):

Thx for the response, apparently there was nothing wrong wit the code ( or maybe there still is and I'm not aware of it :/), but there was a problem with NetBeans. The "clean build" function doesn't really work for some reason, so I needed to manually delete the build ( I hope I'm making sense :p )